# Why Webpack multi-entries config generate bundles with exactly the same size?

Tags: typescript, webpack, bundle, webpack-5

Why Webpack multi-entries config generate bundles with exactly the same size?
The config

```
   ... 
   entry: {
      rootApp: path.resolve(cwd, "./entries/index.tsx"),
      firstApp: path.resolve(cwd, "./entries/first/index.tsx"),
      secondApp: path.resolve(cwd, "./entries/second/index.tsx"),
    },
    output: {
      publicPath: publicUrlOrPath,
      filename: "[name].[fullhash].bundle.js",
      chunkFilename: "[name][chunkhash].bundle.js",
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
      clean: true,
    },
    ....
```